# Many to Many relationship in emberfire

Tags: ember.js, emberfire

I was wondering wether it is possible to create a many to many relationship in emberfire.
I've got the following models:

```
//Employee
name: DS.attr('string'),
position: DS.attr('string'),
accessoryPosition: DS.attr('string'),
education: DS.attr('string'),
experience: DS.attr('string'),
imgUrl: DS.attr('string'),
teachingIn: DS.attr('string'),
subjects: DS.hasMany('subject', {async: true})

//Subject
name: DS.attr('string'),
courseDescriptionUrl: DS.attr('string'),
description: DS.attr('string'),
examDescriptionUrl: DS.attr('string'),
imgUrl: DS.attr('string'),
sportsSubject: DS.attr('boolean'),
outdoorSubject: DS.attr('boolean'),
commonSubject: DS.attr('boolean'),
teachers: DS.hasMany('employee', {async : true})
```

And then in my employee controller:

```
update(subjects) {
      this.get('model.employee').set('subjects',subjects);
      this.get('model.employee').save();

    }
```

But his only adds it to my /employees endpoint. Is there anyway to make the relationship mutual so to speak?

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually add the employ to the subjects. A way to do that would be something like:

```
update(subjects) {
   this.get('model.employee').set('subjects', subjects);
   this.get('model.employee').save();

   subjects.forEach(subject => {
     subject.get('teachers').addObject(subject);
   });
   subjects.invoke('save');
}
```

`Array#pushObject` adds `subject` if it's already not in the array, and `Array#invoke` calls the `save` method on every element of the array.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks locks, I will try this when I get a chance!